# If two total spaces are locally homeomorphic to their base spaces, when will a fibre preserving map between them be continuous?

Tags: general-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $fp = p'g$, where $f$ is continuous, $p$ and $p'$ are local homeomorphisms.

When will $g$ be continuous ?

My reading says it is iff any local (continuous) section $s$ of $p$ over $U$ which is open,  then $gs$ is a section of $p'$ over $f(U).$

However, I can't prove it, even can't understand why $gs$ is a section over $f(U).$

Comment: Please, fix the title.